# How to show the form on click of a button?

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, button, onclick

I am facing a problem. I have created a form where a user has to input the details about a candidate and also upload his/her image. The problem is that in the form there is a button that says "Click To Add More Candidate", so when this button is clicked the same form should reappear under a division called "moreCandidates". Now to achieve this how should I go about it? Things that are coming in my mind is as follows:

1. To create a function in javascript that exactly creates the form contents (ie. all the input fields,etc) and `onclick` of the button "Click To Add More Candidate", call the function under the mentioned division. I can do this as in the past I have done something very similar to this. However, this time I don't think it would be good idea to create the whole form again as I have written a PHP function in between to read a directory.
2. Or the second thought that I have is to have the form code written in a file called candidate.php and call that file with AJAX. The problem here could be that I might be calling the whole form again (whereas I just want to call the contents of the form like the candidate name, and other stuff)

I very confused at the moment, and help from you all would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

My html code:

```
<div id="candidateForm">
    <table border="0">
        <form  method="post" action="formDetails.php" enctype="multipart/form-date">
            <tr>
                <td>Candidate Name:</td>
                <td><input class="candidateForm" type="textbox" name="candidateName" placeholder="Candidate's Name"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Enroll No:</td>
                <td><input class="candidateForm" type="textbox" name="enrollNumber" placeholder="Enroll No"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Candidate Image:</td>
                <td><input class="candidateForm" type="file" name="candidateImage" placeholder="Select a Image"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cadidate Post:</td>
                <?php
                    //This is the target folder that is going to be read.
                    $target="uploads/";

                    //I an using a directory function in PHP scandir() which scans tha contains of the give directory
                    $dir=scandir($target);
                ?>

                <td> 
                    <select name="candidatePost">
                        <option value="candidatePost" select="selected">---------Select---------</option>
                        <?php 
                                foreach($dir as $folders)
                                {
                                    //When we loop throung the target folder/directory we get this annoying two folder that is "." and ".." so just to rule then out i m using an IF condition
                                    if($folders!="."&& $folders!="..")
                                    //echo $folders;
                                    echo "<option class='candidateForm' value=$folders>$folders</option>";
                                }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>About The Candidate:</td>
                <td><textarea name="aboutCandidate" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <div id="moreCandidates"> </div>
            <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Click To Add More Candidate"></input> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="candidateFormSubmit" value="Press Here To Submit The Details" onclick=""/></td>
            </tr>
        </form>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that to send a file to upload _without a full page refresh_, you must submit the form to an iframe. Then, you can listen for the `load` event on that iframe.

Comment: umm i dont have any idea about iframes , i m kinda average newbie, is there any other simpler way to achieve this....

Comment: Its's very simple, and necessary if you want to implement these changes that you are looking to make... Javascript will be required as well.

Comment: Check out [this AJAX upload script](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/).

Comment: hey thanks man ... i will go through it ... if there is any more simpler ways to get this task done ... plz let me know ...